# Alternative formulation of the Collatz problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, recurrence-relations, collatz-conjecture

Just for the sake of interest, I have realized that the additive step in the Collatz function can be technically avoided when computing the function iterates.

Rather than defining the Collatz function as
$$ T_0(n) = \begin{cases}
 (3n + 1)/2 &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$,} \\
 n/2        &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$,}
\end{cases} $$
and tracking the trajectory directly on $n$, one can track the same trajectory on $n+1$ with the function
$$ T_1(n) = \begin{cases}
 (n+1)/2 &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$,} \\
 3n/2    &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$.}
\end{cases} $$
Thus the "multiplying by 3" just moved to the "even" branch.

The trick is that, when calculating the function iterates, we switch between $n$ and $n+1$ in such a way that we always use only the "even" branch of either $T_0$ or $T_1$.
Therefore, the above functions can be expressed as
$$ T_0(n) = \begin{cases}
 T_1(n+1)-1 &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$,} \\
 n/2        &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$,}
\end{cases} $$
and
$$ T_1(n) = \begin{cases}
 T_0(n-1)+1 &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$,} \\
 3n/2       &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$.}
\end{cases} $$

There are seemingly still two additions.
However, considering the binary representation of the $n$, these additions can be avoided using right shifts and [operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) which count the number of one/zero bits following the least significant zero/non-zero bit.
The powers of three can be precomputed in a look-up table.

I am just interested in knowing whether this formulation has appeared before?
Is this a special case of some other known (more general) recurrence relation?
Any feedback is welcome.

**UPDATE:** Some simple code to illustrate my idea can be found [here](https://github.com/xbarin02/collatz/). Currently, I am able to verify the convergence of all numbers below $2^{40}$ in approximatelly 4 minutes (single-threaded program running at 2.40GHz CPU).

Comment: I could mention that the oddness and evenness is unimportant in the sense that the entire Collatz function can be transformed into a boolean equivalent where any even binary number is expressed as the input to the function, where $2n$ is the mapping to any odd and even input. There is a special to do this, but I leave that as an exercise, because there are many different ways to do this. So afaik the $3$ multiplier is not really that relevant if you study it from internal mechanics standpoint (in binary). I find that we don't need to find the exponent, but compute it using the xor-operation.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy Can you explain the idea about using the xor to find the exponent a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure that such cosmetic transformations make you progress towards the goal. I prefer the definition with odd numbers only (discarding the trailing zeroes every time), but again, this doesn't make the resolution any simpler.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Anyhow, I can check all numbers below 2^31 in about six seconds using the simple code I have linked (single threaded, 2.4 GHz CPU).

Comment: @DaBler: is that deemed to be impressive ?

Comment: Your code looks similar to $\frac{3^Un+3^U-2^U}{2^U}$ found here https://youtu.be/lNzzlFWWiDo?t=344, in the video he talks about cycles, but I noticed if you plug in odd n, and replace U with the number of trailing ones in n, you get the next 2 mod 6 number in n's collatz sequence.

Comment: @PrincePolka Good point. Indeed, this really corresponds to a series of steps in the $n + 1$ domain. Although the video doesn't mention fast implementation tricks using bit-manipulating operations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust According to [this paper](http://www.ijnc.org/index.php/ijnc/article/view/135) from 2017, the authors can verify the convergence for all numbers below $2^{32}$ in about a second (using a CPU implementation). So at least, I'm not so far away from the state-of-the-art...

Comment: @DaBler If you want to test even less numbers here's an idea.  
Show that numbers that never reach $5 \mod 6$ must converge.  
Show that $5 \mod 6$ numbers go to $5 \mod 12$.  
Show that $5 \mod 12$ number go to $8 \mod 18$.  
Test $8 \mod 18$ numbers only.  
Not 100% sure it's correct, but it could be, note I'm talking about the standard collatz rules now.

Comment: If anybody is interested, the current version of my program is able to verify the convergence of all numbers below $2^{40}$ in less than 20 seconds (on Intel Xeon E5-2680 v4).

Comment: Subsequent question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330085/computational-verification-of-collatz-problem

Comment: There are errors in the formulas. The correct formulas:
$$
T_0(n) = \begin{cases}
 T_1(n+1)-1 &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$,} \\
 n/2      &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$,}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
T_1(n) = \begin{cases}
 T_0(n-1)+1 &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$,} \\
 3n/2     &\quad \text{ if $n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: @miracle173 Yes you are right. I will fix it. I wanted to demonstrate that at this point you switch to tracking $T1$ instead of $T0$, and _vice versa_. So a trajectory can be, e.g. $n, T0(n), T0^2(n), T1^3(n), T1^4(n), T0^5(n)$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to @BaBler's comment.
The formula for finding trailing zeros is: $n\oplus(n-1)$, i.e., in Boolean form.
To get a pow$2$ number we must add $+1$ to that or else it will just give trailing $1$'s. 
We must then subtract $1$ from the result and take the base $2$ logarithm.
Here is the complete form:

$$v_2(n)=\log_2(n\oplus(n-1))$$

$$C(n) = \frac{3n+1}{2^{v_2(3n+1)}}$$

Input to this function must (only) be odd numbers: $2n+1$.

**Code**

```
n = (3 * n + 1) >> (int)log2((3 * n + 1) ^ (3 * n));
```

Since $n\oplus(n-1)$ gives $2^x-1$, the $\log_2$ rounds off to nearest exponent which is actually the number of trailing zeroes.

This is also known as the **Reduced Collatz Function**.

Comment: We did not actually need to add $1$ to the result of the xor. Because it's integer operation.

Comment: This seems to be incredibly inefficient way to compute the number of trailing zeros (which is a single instruction in modern CPUs). Have I missed somethink?

Comment: If you are only out after efficiency on modern CPUs then you should stick to what you think is best.