# Distributed computing project to check the convergence of the Collatz problem

Tags: algorithms, computational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

I am about to start a distributed computing project to check the convergence of the Collatz problem.
So far, the convergence of the problem has been verified for all numbers below $87 \times 2^{60} \approx 2^{66.4}$.
See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314430/how-far-has-collatz-conjecture-been-computationally-verified) for details.

The algorithm which I intend to use is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330085/computational-verification-of-collatz-problem).
After some thought, I have decided to divide the problem into sub-problems, each having the size of $2^{40}$ numbers.
Now I am facing a question of how to verify that each sub-problem has been verified correctly (i.e. the worker does not cheat).

For convenience, the algorithm which verifies a particular $n = n_0$ is as follows:
\begin{align}
\text{repeat} &~ \\
n &← n + 1 \\
\alpha &← \operatorname{ctz}(n) \\
n &← n × 3^\alpha / 2^\alpha \\
n &← n − 1 \\
\beta &← \operatorname{ctz}(n) \\
n &← n / 2^{\beta} \\
\text{until } &~ n < n_0\text{,}
\end{align}
where the $\operatorname{ctz}$ is the [count trailing zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) operator.

My idea so far is to sum all the $\alpha$s (or $\beta$s, or both) for all $n$ inside the specified sub-problem ($2^{40}$ numbers). This sum seems to be quite independent of the magnitude of the numbers tested. Someone else could then independently verify this checksum (i.e. double-checking). Is this a good way or do you have a better idea (to prevent cheating)?

Comment: You might be interested in: https://boinc.thesonntags.com/collatz/

Comment: And this: https://www.reddit.com/r/CasualMath/comments/7w78at/how_far_has_collatz_been_proved/dupmrgo/

Comment: In general, double-checking some sort of hash value for a given ''chunk'' is a good idea to make sure no-one is cheating. You can compute the probability of a double false positive for your hash function and choose an appropriate one accordingly.

Comment: @Klangen Basically, the dilemma I am dealing with is whether to implement this double-checking on my side, or only to publish those checksums so that anyone else can verify my results.

Comment: It would not make much sense publishing the hashes, as that does not discourage cheating. The "double-checking" as you call it has to be done in a "private" way

Comment: For those who are interested, [here is an article](https://rdcu.be/b5nn1) about this algorithm.